# Edit Word header with Find/Replace

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I would also like to modify the header of a Word doc from Excel macro by searching for a string, then extending the selection by 8 chars and replacing with another string.  So far all examples either don't modify the header or a debug error displays on any .Find.

Help!!!

Comment: Please be a bit more specific when asking a question: What have you tried so far, with a code example? ([I downvoted because there is no code](//idownvotedbecau.se/nocode/)) / What do you expect? / What error do you get? For help, take a look at "[How to ask](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)".

Comment: Kindly post the code you're having trouble with, showing how you're starting Word, accessing the document - and accessing the content in the document header.

Comment: You might benefit from reading 
[Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/3219613)

Answer (score 0):

This really is quite straightforward:

```
Sub DocUpdate()
' Note: This code requires a VBA Reference to MS Word.
' See under Tools|References in the VBA Editor.
Dim wdApp As Word.Application, WdDoc As Word.Document
Dim StrNm As String, StrFnd As String, StrRep As String
StrNm = "C:\Users\" & Environ(Username) & "\My Documents\MyFile.doc"
StrFnd = "ABCD????????"
StrRep = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A1").Value
If Dir(StrNm) <> "" Then
  Set wdApp = New Word.Application
  With wdApp
    .Visible = True
    Set WdDoc = Documents.Open(Filename:=StrNm, AddToRecentFiles:=False, Visible:=True)
    With WdDoc
      With .Sections.First.Headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range.Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .Replacement.ClearFormatting
        .Format = False
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Text = StrFnd
        .Replacement.Text = StrRep
        .MatchWildcards = True
        .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
      End With
    .Close True
    End With
    .Quit
  End With
  MsgBox "File: " & StrNm & " updated.", vbInformation
Else
  MsgBox "File: " & StrNm & " not found.", vbCritical
End If
Set WdDoc = Nothing: Set wdApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

where StrNm holds the path & name for the document, 'ABCD' is the string to find, and StrRep holds the replacement text.

Comment: This does most of what is needed.  I need to find the text, then extend the selection to the end of the word found and then replace.  Is this possible??

Comment: Your original post said you want to extend the selection by 8 chars, which I showed how to do. As I said «'ABCD' is the string to find» - ???????? does the extension. If you want to extend to the end of the current word regardless of the # of characters, use ABCD*>.